# Resize pictureboxes on map when form resize

Tags: c#, .net, resize, picturebox

Hello im currently creating a map thats shows a route to diffrent classes at my school

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SnUc.png

It looks like this with a big picturebox contanining the whole map and is docked to the form, then there is alot of pictureboxes with a red dot, that is positions and is hidden until a specific position is selected then the right one will show up and tell where the room is.

Now my problem is that i want to have the ability to resize the form and still have the right positions of the red dots on the map at exact same place just with a bigger size og smaller. Because if i change the size now it will do this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKKdo.png

It does the same when the program is running and i cant figure out how to make it so the picturebox'es resizes and takes the same place on the map when the form is resizeing.

I hope someone understands the problem and want to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to recalculate the positions of your dot pictureboxes relative to the resizing of your map picturebox.

As a starting point you need the old x- and y-position of your dot picturebox as well as as the height and width of your map picturebox as they were before the resizing took effect.

After the resizing you should have the new width and heigth of your map picturebox.

From this you can calculate the resize ratio, that you need to calculate the new position of your dot picturebox.

Roughly like this:

```
newDotXPosition = oldDotXPosition * (newMapWidth / oldMapWidth)
newDotYPosition = oldDotYPosition * (newMapHeigth / oldMapHeight)
```

The sizes of the dot pictureboxes could be dealt with accordingly.

Here is my working code, i extracted the relevant parts:

```
private int oldXPosition;
private int oldYPosition;
private double oldMapWidth;
private double oldMapHeight;

public Form1()
{
  //stuff, etc
  oldXPosition = pictureBox2.Location.X;
  oldYPosition = pictureBox2.Location.Y;
  oldMapWidth= Width;
  oldMapHeight = Height;
}

private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int newXPosition = (int)(oldXPosition * (Width / oldMapWidth));
  int newYPosition = (int)(oldYPosition * (Height / oldMapHeight));
  pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newXPosition, newYPosition);
}
```

That's it. Nothing more. I made oldMapWidth/Height double to avoid integer division.

Comment: Thanks alot, i will try this and return back if it helped or not :-)

Comment: Hmmm dosent seem to work correct, when resizeing a bit i dosent move, but if i put fullscreen it moves a bit but still at the wrong place

Comment: I store oldDotxPosition, oldDotYPosition, oldMapWidth/Height in the form's constructor, since they never need to change for the calculation. In the form's resize eventhandler i calculate the new location like shown above and set this as the new location, `pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newDotXPosition, newDotYPosition)`. I got it working here. Maybe you want to show some code?

Comment: @mgcmartin Why do you use the click eventhandler? Just clicking a button doesn't change your form's size, so nothing will happen. Put that code in the form's resize event handler. (pictureBox1 is the map, right? i assume it is anchored to fill the form?)

Comment: it was just for testing with the button, picturebox1 is the map and 2 is the dot. The Picture1 is docked onto the form and i have tryed with the form resize event it dosent work

Comment: @mgcmartin The code i just posted works here for me. Have a look and see what you can take from it.

Comment: I got it working sort off now, but its fine for my use, Thankss alot for the help. :-)